# Edit pixel values

Tags: java, image, pixel

How to edit pixel values of an image in Java. Is there any method to change pixel values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
BufferedImage image = ...
image.setRGB(x, y, 0);
```

From [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
 void setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)
 //Sets a pixel in this BufferedImage to the specified RGB value.
```

Comment: can we change a few pixels using this?I tried the same method to change few pixels.But the output image is not showing the changes

Comment: Yes, you can change any or all of the pixels in the image.

Comment: Do you call drawImage on the image after the operation? setRGB changes the pixels in the memory buffer, not on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

In `BufferedImage`: public void setRGB(int x,
                   int y,
                   int rgb)

> Sets a pixel in this BufferedImage to
>   the specified RGB value. The pixel is
>   assumed to be in the default RGB color
>   model, TYPE_INT_ARGB, and default sRGB
>   color space. For images with an
>   IndexColorModel, the index with the
>   nearest color is chosen.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html