# How to swap pixels of an image randomly?

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, bufferedimage

I've been working on a Java program that reads an image, subdivides it into a definable number of rectangular tiles, then swaps the pixels of each tile with those of another tile, and then puts them back together and renders the image.

An explanation of the idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ENkX.png

I've been using the `BufferedImage` class, so my idea was to first read all `width * height` pixels from its data buffer and save them to an array.

Then, according to the tile height and width, copy the entire pixel information of each tile to small arrays, shuffle those, and then write back the data contained in these arrays to their position in the data buffer. It should then be enough to create a new `BufferedImage` with the original color and sample models as well as the updated data buffer.

However, I got ominous errors when creating a new `WriteableRaster` from the updated data buffer, and the number of pixels didn't match up (I had suddenly gotten 24 instead of originally 8, and so forth), so I figured there is something wrong with the way I address the pixel information.

( Reference pages for [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and [WriteableRaster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) )

I used the following loop to iterate through the 1D data buffer:

```
// maximum iteration values
int numRows = height/tileHeight;
int numCols = width/tileWidth;

// cut picture into tiles

// for each column of the image matrix
// addressing columns (1D)
for ( int column = 0; column < numCols; column++ )
{
    // for each row of the matrix
    // addressing cells (2D)
    for ( int row = 0; row < numRows; row++ )
    {
        byte[] pixels = new byte[(tileWidth+1) * (tileHeight+1)];
        int celloffset = (column + (width * row)); // find cell base address

        // for each row inside the cell
        // adressing column inside a tile (3D)
        for ( int colpixel = 0; colpixel < tileWidth; colpixel++ )
        {
            // for each column inside the tile -> each pixel of the cell
            for ( int rowpixel = 0; rowpixel < tileHeight; rowpixel++ )
            {
                // address of pixel in original image buffer array allPixels[]
                int origpos = celloffset + ((rowpixel * tileWidth) + colpixel);

                // translated address of pixel in local pixels[] array of current tile
                int transpos = colpixel + (rowpixel * tileWidth);

                // source, start, dest, offset, length 
                pixels[transpos] = allPixels[origpos];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code? Or is there perhaps a much easier way to do this that I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: I suggest posting a complete program that people can try and run, I believe it increases the probability that you will get useful help.

Comment: Creating subimages and drawing to a new image wasn't an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below edits the image in place. So no need to create new objects, which should simplify. If you need to keep the original, just copy it entirely first. Also, no need to save to separate arrays.

Since you said "shuffle" I assume you want to swap the tiles randomly. I made a function for that, and if you just call it many times you will end up with tiles swapped randomly. If you want a pattern or some other rule of how they are swapped, just call the other function directly with your chosen tiles.

I haven't used BufferedImage before, but looking at the documentation,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

and this post,

[Edit pixel values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702397/edit-pixel-values)

It seems that an easy way is to use the methods getRGB and setRGB

`int    getRGB(int x, int y)`

> Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model
>   (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace.

`void   setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)`

> Sets a pixel in this BufferedImage to the specified RGB value.

I would try something like the following: (untested code)

Using random http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

```
int numRows = height/tileHeight;
int numCols = width/tileWidth;

void swapTwoRandomTiles (BufferedImage b) {
    //choose x and y coordinates randomly for the tiles
    int xt1 = random.nextInt (numCols);
    int yt1 = random.nextInt (numRows);
    int xt2 = random.nextInt (numCols);
    int yt2 = random.nextInt (numRows);

    swapTiles (b,xt1,yt1,xt2,yt2);
}

void swapTiles(BufferedImage b, int xt1, int yt1, int xt2, int yt2) {
    int tempPixel = 0;
    for (int x=0; x<tileWidth; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<tileHeight; y++) {
            //save the pixel value to temp
            tempPixel = b.getRGB(x + xt1*tileWidth, y + yt1*tileHeight);
            //write over the part of the image that we just saved, getting data from the other tile
            b.setRGB ( x + xt1*tileWidth, y + yt1*tileHeight, b.getRGB ( x+xt2*tileWidth, y+yt2*tileHeight));
            //write from temp back to the other tile
            b.setRGB ( x + xt2*tileWidth, y + yt2*tileHeight, tempPixel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, good idea. I'll try it out and report back. Thank you until then!

Comment: Okay, worked it into my code and it works perfectly. Thank you for real this time, I thought it much more complicate.