# Java - editing an image

Tags: java, image

Is it possible to edit a image in java?
I mean to draw a pixel in a certain RGB color in a certain spot and save the image.

I'm working on a game where the objects are loaded by an image and in order to save the current state of the map I need to edit some pixels and load it later.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702397/edit-pixel-values

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. If you create an instance of BufferedImage, which is an object that stores image data, you will be able to get the pixels and change them. Here is how:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
    BufferedImage newImage = orgiginalImage;
    int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)newImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){
        // Code for changing pixel data;
        pixels[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF // White
        // Syntax for setting pixel color: 0x(HEX COLOR CODE)
        // There is no need to set these pixels to the image; they are allerady linked
        // For instance, if you create a Canvas object in a JFrame, 
        // and used graphics.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0,
        // newImage.getWidth(), newImage.getHeight(), null), it will be up to date
        // Another example is, if you saved newImage to a file, it willallready have
        // the white pixels drawn in.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I have done it a bit differently, once I start a new game I create a new Image and edit it with BufferedImage => image.setRGB(x,y,rgb) when I remove/kill something